# How to make div take up 100vh height minus the height of the header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive

I am trying to set up a hero section where the div takes up 100vh minus the height of the header. I originally set the css height property to calc(100vh - 310px). 310px is the height of the header on my monitor. However I am trying to find a responsive solution, where the height of the header is dynamic and can change based on screen size. Not sure how to go about doing this. I assume it is not possible using css and am fine using javascript/jquery to solve this.

```
<header></header>
<div class="heroSection"></div>

.heroSection {
   height: calc(100vh - 310px)
}
```

Comment: Hey @termain Afif mind linking to where this was asked before, because I've searched for a way to do this without finding any results

Comment: the link is on the top of your actual question ;) and you need to carefully read all the answers/comments and you will find more than one way to do this with only CSS

Answer (score -1):

You could use `fill-available` property for this.

```
.heroSection {
    height: -moz-available;          /* WebKit-based browsers will ignore this. */
    height: -webkit-fill-available;  /* Mozilla-based browsers will ignore this. */
    height: fill-available;
}
```